# Interchanging of limit and complex integral operators

Tags: complex-analysis

(Q) Assume $f(z)$ is analytic in the punctured neighbourhood of $z_{0},$ and $z_{0}$ is a simple pole of $f .$ Prove that
$$
\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{C_{e}} f(z) d z=i\left(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1}\right) \operatorname{Res}\left(f, z_{0}\right)
$$
where $C_{\epsilon}: z=z_{0}+\epsilon e^{i \theta}, 0<\theta_{1} \leq \theta \leq \theta_{2}, \epsilon>0$

My attempt:

Which is the supporting fact that I could write

$\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}f(z_0+\epsilon e^{i \theta})i \epsilon e^{i \theta}d \theta=i \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\epsilon e^{i \theta}f(z_0+\epsilon e^{i \theta})d \theta=i \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}(\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0 }(z-z_0)f(z))d \theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine. Interchange of limit and integral is justified by the fact that $(z-z_0)f(z)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$ so we can use Bounded Convergence Theorem.